# Recall windows to the current space

Tags: window-manager, spaces

Is there a way to recall an app to the current space?

This is possible by turning Spaces off, but that recalls all apps. I just want one.

Sometimes a Safari URL gets opened, and since there is a Safari window open on some desktops somewhere, there it goes. It takes a few minutes to find where the link opened. If I could just recall the browser to the current space, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fetch that window to the current space, but if you switch to the appropriate space where that window is located, you can click on the window title and while holding down the mouse button, press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to return that window the first space (or hold down <kbd>control</kbd> + whatever number space you want to drag it to).

Comment: Wow, very cool, I didn't know about that. That'll save a bunch of time compared to the dragging-to-the-edge-repeatedly thing I've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any gathering feature. You can quickly move windows between spaces by activating it with the <kbd>F6</kbd> key (or whatever you've set it to in *Exposé & Spaces Preferences*) to display all of them at once and, in that mode, drag windows from one space to another, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> again to return to normal viewing.